# Plot 2 tmap objects side-by-side

Tags: r, graphics, choropleth, tmap

**Example:**

I want to plot two [tmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/index.html) plots side by side, which are generated by this code.

```
library(tmap)
library(gridExtra)

data(World)

plot1=
  tm_shape(World, projection = "merc") + 
  tm_layout("", inner.margins=c(-1.72, -2.05, -0.75, -1.56)) +
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.3, lwd=2)

plot2=
  tm_shape(World, projection = "merc") + 
  tm_layout("", inner.margins=c(-1.72, -2.05, -0.75, -1.56)) +
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.3, lwd=2)
```

`plot1` and `plot2` work fine as single stand-alone plots:
[image]

**Problem:**

I have problems to put both plots side-by-side. I tried:

`grid.arrange(plot1, plot2)` throughs an error `Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main, : input must be grob!`. I thought that this should work (using [gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html)) as [tmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/index.html) seems to be based on the `grid graphics system`.

Also `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` does not work as it shows only one plot (guess this is related as `tmap` plot does not follow the `base graphics system`).

**Question:**

How can I plot both objects `plot1` and `plot2` side-by-side (`ncol=2`)?

**Update**:

Regarding the proposed grid-based solution, I get overlapping plots instead of two column arranged plots.

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tmap_1.0    dplyr_0.4.3 sp_1.1-1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1     class_7.3-11       classInt_0.1-23    colorspace_1.2-6   DBI_0.3.1          digest_0.6.8       e1071_1.6-4        ggplot2_1.0.1     
 [9] grid_3.1.2         gridBase_0.4-7     gtable_0.1.2       lattice_0.20-29    magrittr_1.5       MASS_7.3-35        munsell_0.4.2      parallel_3.1.2    
[17] plyr_1.8.3         proto_0.3-10       R6_2.1.1           raster_2.3-40      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 Rcpp_0.12.2        reshape2_1.4.1     rgdal_0.8-16      
[25] rgeos_0.3-11       scales_0.3.0       stringi_1.0-1      stringr_1.0.0      tools_3.1.2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice question!

`grid.arrange` doesn't support tmap plots (yet?) in the same way it supports `ggplot2` plots.

There are two options:

1) Use small multiples by assigning two values to an aesthetic (see examples from `tm_facets`). Your plots don't use aesthetics, but you can trick this as follows:

```
tm_shape(World, projection = "merc") + 
  tm_fill(col=c("white", "white")) +
  tm_layout("", inner.margins=c(-1.72, -2.05, -0.75, -1.56)) +
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.3, lwd=2)
```

2) Use the `grid` package to define viewports:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(1,2)))
print(plot1, vp=viewport(layout.pos.col = 1))
print(plot2, vp=viewport(layout.pos.col = 2))
```

Another thing, rather than clipping the shape with negative inner margins, you could also use the bounding box arguments inside `tm_shape`:

```
tm_shape(World, projection = "merc", xlim=c(-2e6, 6.5e6), ylim=c(-4e6, 8.5e6)) + 
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.3, lwd=2)
```

It produces the same map, but it the code a little cleaner.

Comment: Thx a lot, unfortunately still have 2 issues: a) the grid based solution plots to plots but they do overlap. b) the solution using multiples create two plot well aligned but in 1 column instead of 2.

Comment: Could you post an image of issue a? As for issue b, the number is rows and columns is automatically determined by the aspect ratio of the graphics device, and those of the shape(s). You can set this manually with `+tm_facets(ncol=2)`

Comment: It's working for me. Could you share your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Ah, just what I thought! `tmap` 1.2 has been released two weeks ago on CRAN, where this viewport bug has been fixed.

Comment: Thx a lot, unfortunately the OS X Mavericks binaries on CRAN is still on v1.0.

Answer (score 12):

tmap_arrange()

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/tmap.pdf

```
data(World)
w1 <- qtm(World, projection = "eck4", title="Eckert IV")
w2 <- qtm(World, projection = "merc", title="Mercator")
w3 <- qtm(World, projection = "wintri", title="Winkel-Tripel")
w4 <- qtm(World, projection = "robin", title="Robinsin")

current.mode <- tmap_mode("plot")
tmap_arrange(w1, w2, w3, w4)
tmap_mode(current.mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if in the meantime it has become possible to plot the 5 maps in the following example side by side without switching to `tm_facets(ncol=5)`.

```
data(NLD_prov, NLD_muni)

tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
tm_fill(c("pop_0_14", "pop_15_24", "pop_25_44", "pop_45_64", "pop_65plus"),
        style="kmeans", 
        palette=list("Oranges", "Greens", "Blues", "Purples", "Greys"),
        title=c("Population 0 to 14", "Population 15 to 24", "Population 25 to 44",
                "Population 45 to 64", "Population 65 and older")) +
tm_shape(NLD_prov) +
tm_borders() +
tm_format_NLD(frame = TRUE, asp=0)
```